# How do I deal with the array out of bounds exception when creating a new git branch from a past commit in Visual Studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio

> Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.

This is what I get in the Team Explorer tab when I try to create a new branch to one of the previous commits. I've had this error happen in the past, and updating to the most recent version of VS 2017 (15.9.7) just now made no difference. In the past the only way I've managed to get around this problem is by branching out to some other commit, but now this really hit me where it hurts.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone faces this problem in the future, just like I did and stumbled upon this thread, I share my scenario and how it was solved:

Scenario:
We Squashed and merged a huge branch with integration branch which resulted in the top commit on integration branch to be a huge one (over 900 files changed).
Once integration had this huge commit on top we were blocked from checking out to it (We got the same error like mentioned in this thread) and if we used command line/other git control to checkout to integration, we got this error also when we tried to create new branches from it.

This error happened on all our devices and on VS2019 + VS2022

Solution:
Use git commands / another git control to checkout to the branch resulting in this problem. Commit and push a small commit message. It should go back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Using `git checkout` from the command line worked for me.

More specifically, `git checkout <commit> -b temp` where `<commit>` is the commit id. What this did is create a branch named `temp` similarly to how it would be done using the IDE.

I have no idea why this error occurs for me, but while looking at similar issues I noticed that people managed to get around using git commands from the command line.  It worked fine enough here.

Comment: How is `git checkout` from a command line a solution for creating a branch within the Visual Studio IDE? This is unlikely the correct solution to the specific question you posed, which lacks way too much detail (such as how you went about creating a branch and what state your git repo and solution were in at the time). Your "solution" is a silly non-sequitur to the question you posed regarding your specific, unusual branching issue.

Comment: The IDE will automatically update itself once the new branch is created. I tried `git checkout` in the solution folder and the tool was helpful enough to suggest I use `-b <branch>`. I can't even begin to guess as to why this issue is occuring for me. This is something I've run into when creating new branches from far off commits. This is the first time this has happened when branching from a 3 hours old commit.

Comment: Based on what you wrote, I wonder if you're doing things in the Git command line that Visual Studio doesn't expect to be done...? Either way--as you discovered, I can't really see a good reason why the age of a commit should play a role in the ability to branch from it.

Comment: No, I haven't used Git from the command line on this project up to now. I am not sure if it has anything to do with the commit's age either. I haven't observed a clear pattern on where this error occurs.

Comment: This happened to me today and happened when trying to branch from a large squashed commit with 982 lines in the commit text that if saved to a text file took about 35 kb.  Using the command line to create the new branch worked and then after then next commit to that branch there was no issue creating new branches from the later commits.  I'm wondering if the size of the commit message has an impact on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to overload of commits cache in local, since it's specific to Visual Studio

- Option 1 : use git bash git checkout
- Option 2 : Take a local repo
  backup, delete it and clone it one more time

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and I made the following steps:
Go to: Visual Studio -> Team Explorer -> Branches
Step 1: Remove the local Branches that you do not need any more
Step 2: on each remaining local Branches I right click and select Reset -> Delete changes (hard)

*Probably not need existing changes once you start to work on another branch.*

Answer (score 0):

I've got such error and in my case it had happened because of not installed git I believe. Because when I installed it it worked.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32980493)

Comment: alright @EgoPingvina, thank you, but I just shared what helped for me ...

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happen as well.
Scenario: if we have a solution that uses the .net framework, and add in a .net core project under that solution (even if it is not set to build), Visual Studio can throw the 'array out of bounds error' because it fails to resolve a dependency, and never actually calls any git commands.

To repro this: (well, what I did)
use VS 2019 and create a solution with with a .net framework project.

Then open that solution in VS 2022 and create a .net core 6.0 project from VS 2022 in the solution. Make sure you have a nuget package that requires the .net 6 core.

Open the solution up again in vs 2019 and set this project to not build under the solution.

Merge that into your baseline.

You will get the error listed in this report.  Not sure if that was the OP problem, but it definitely has something to do with VS resolving dependencies in the .sln file and not even calling git to do it's job.

The 'solution' is to remove the offending project from the solution, then check that in.  My guess is to start removing your projects from the solution one at a time to see what is causing the error. That problem will need to be solved in some manner.

It seems the problem is specific to Visual Studio, and is not related to git.